# How do redirecting, in my exception, if exception call on controller, which render in twig

Tags: symfony, twig-extension

I need to redirect from the controller rendered in twig, which is available in the example along the route "/login_form"

On production don't work, on dev work, i'm confused as to how to get this code to work in the producion?

Symfony 3.4

The code is made only as an example for the test

services.yml:

```
services:
    kernel.listener.redirectexception:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\RedirectExceptionListener
        arguments:
            - "@router"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

DefaultController.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Exception\RedirectException;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->getUser()) {
          throw new RedirectException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }
        return $this->render('default/login.html.twig', []);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login_form", name="login_form")
     */
    public function loginFormAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('default/login_form.html.twig', []);
    }
}
```

RedirectExceptionListener.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use AppBundle\Exception\RedirectException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class RedirectExceptionListener
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        if ((!$event->getException()->getPrevious() instanceof RedirectException)
              && (!$event->getException() instanceof RedirectException)) {
            return;
        }
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('homepage'));
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }

}
```

login_form.html.twig:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Default:login')) }}
```

Comment: Can you give us the result of: php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher "kernel.exception" for both environments please

Comment: Did you clear cache for `prod` environment executing `php bin/console cache:clear -e prod`?

Comment: @DrKey, yes, i clear cache for production

Comment: @albert,
`#1      AppBundle\EventListener\RedirectExceptionListener::onKernelException()              0
#2      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException()    0
#3      Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onException()   0
#4      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException()   -128`
prod and dev differ only ProfilerListener

Comment: This is for development can you run it for production: php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher "kernel.exception"  --env prod

Comment: @albert, prod and dev differ only ProfilerListener, in prod ProfilerListener without